# installation of netbeans along with the phpmyadmin, xamp server and wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, netbeans

I want to ask a question regarding installation of netbeans on window10. I have installed xamp server , phpmyadmin and wordpress after the installation of netbeans. In he process of installing the phpmyadmin i have to uninstall the mysql and reinstall it for proper working of phpmyadmin. Now I want to make a project on netbeans but as it will use mysql for backend process (connecivity form database). So now mysql is present in my system but still can't be used for netbeans.what should I do?

Comment: Hi, you can simply proceed towards `File > New Project` in Netbeans

Comment: What error you are getting while connecting?
Which language you are using?
What is the code of connecting to the database?
Please provide some useful information while asking...!!

Comment: I want to make a mini project using netbeans(front end) and mysql(back end) . netbeans is installed already and mysql is installed along with phpmyadmin. should i installed mysql explicitly?